# How to explode list of strings in Pandas to a single list without losing the order of data points

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

I am storing some integer values as list of strings (Varchar type) in Redshift as Redshift does not support list [] data-types . Now for some analysis purpose I need to convert a list of strings (containing integer values) to a 1-D int array .

Sample Data :

```
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,2,3],'values':[['[1]','[1,8]'],['[3,7]','[3]'],'[5]'] })
print(dummy_df)
```

Output Data :

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,2,3],'values':[[1,1,8],[3,7,3],[5]] })
final_df
```

**NOTE:** DataFrame dummy_df value-column is a list of strings

Answer (score 2):

Try the (hopefully self-explained) following code:

```
dummy_df['values'] = (dummy_df['values'].explode()     # flatten the list structure
                          .str.extractall('(\d+)')     # extract the digits
                          .astype(int)                 # convert to int
                          .groupby(level=0).agg(list)  # aggregate the list
                     )

print(dummy_df.to_dict('list'))
```

Output:

```
{'customer_id': [1, 2, 3], 'values': [[1, 1, 8], [3, 7, 3], [5]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way with a slow apply would be to eval those strings to lists and then sum.

```
import ast

dummy_df['values'] = dummy_df['values'].explode().apply(ast.literal_eval).sum(level=0)

   customer_id     values
0            1  [1, 1, 8]
1            2  [3, 7, 3]
2            3        [5]
```

---

Regardless, complex object manipulation with pandas scales fairly poorly. @QuangHoang's method is slightly faster.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ast


def quang(df):
    return (df['values'].explode()              # flatten the list structure
               .str.extractall('(\d+)')         # extract the digits
               .astype(int)                     # convert to int
               .groupby(level=0).agg(list))[0]  # aggregate the list
           
    
def alollz(df):
    return df['values'].explode().apply(ast.literal_eval).sum(level=0)



perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,2,3],
                                             'values':[['[1]','[1,8]'], ['[3,7]','[3]'], '[5]']})]*n,
                              ignore_index=True), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: quang(df),
        lambda df: alollz(df),
    ],
    labels=['str.extract', 'ast.literal_eval'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 16)],
    equality_check=lambda x,y: x.compare(y).empty,
    xlabel='~len(df)'
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Alollz .. this approach also works perfectly . And thanks a lot for the performance benchmark graph :)

Comment: @ashish yeah I was hoping it would be slightly faster than QuangHoang's but alas apply is very slow. But as you can see, even the built-in pandas string methods are rather slow for string/object manipulations. At least it's slightly less code :D